# Calling sf::RectangleShapes draw function?

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

I have a simple set of classes. One of them is a `ButtonComponent` where I want to essentially use `sf::RectangleShape` for the visual aspect and then the rest of the `ButtonComponent` would handle things such as event Listeners. The problem comes in the form that if I inherit from `sf::Drawable` in the parent class I have to implement `draw()` (`Component` class) which means the child classes implement the parents `draw()` and not the SFML Shapes `draw()` function. Is there some way of either restructuring the two classes or a way to call `sf::RectangleShapes` draw function?

**Component.h**

```
class Component : public sf::Drawable {
public:
    Component();
    virtual ~Component();
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const = 0;
};

class ButtonComponent : public sf::RectangleShape, public Component {
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states);
};
```

Comment: "Is there some way of either restructuring the two classes or a way to call `sf::RectangleShapes` draw function?" What hinders you to call `sf::RectangleShapes::draw()` actually?

Comment: it is a private function...

Comment: It's private, because it's supposed to be called by render targets only. If you want to draw a drawable, you'll have to call the reverse one: `myRenderTarget.draw(myDrawable);` This will then internally call the `draw()` member of the actual drawable.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is to have your child classes only inherit `sf::Drawable` and have a `sf::RectangleShape` inside of your child classes. Something similar to below

```
class Component : public sf::Drawable {
public:
    Component();
    virtual ~Component();
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const = 0;
};

class ButtonComponent : public Component {
public:
    ButtonComponent(const sf::Vector2f &size = sf::Vector2f(0, 0));

    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;

    void setSize(const sf::Vector2f& size);
    const sf::Vector2f& getSize() const;
    virtual unsigned int getPointCount() const;
    virtual sf::Vector2f getPoint(unsigned int index) const;
    void setTexture(const sf::Texture* texture, bool resetRect = false);
    void setTextureRect(const sf::IntRect &rect);
    void setFillColor(const sf::Color &color);
    void setOutlineColor(const sf::Color &color);
    void setOutlineThickness(float thickness);
    const sf::Texture* getTexture() const;
    const sf::IntRect& getTextureRext() const;
    const sf::Color& getFillColor() const;
    const sf::Color& getOutlineColor() const;
    float getOutlineThickness() const;
    sf::FloatRect getLocalBounds() const;
    sf::FloatRect getGlobalBounds() const;
    void setPosition(float x, float y);
    void setPosition(const sf::Vector2f &position);
    void setRotation(float angle);
    void setScale(float factorX, float factorY);
    void setScale(const sf::Vector2f& factors);
    void setOrigin(float x, float y);
    void setOrigin(const sf::Vector2f& origin);
    const sf::Vector2f& getPosition() const;
    float getRotation() const;
    const sf::Vector2f& getScale() const;
    const sf::Vector2f& getOrigin() const;
    void move(float offsetX, float offsetY);
    void move(const sf::Vector2f& offset);
    void rotate(float angle);
    void scale(float factorX, float factorY);
    void scale(const sf::Vector2f& factor);
    const sf::Transform& getTransform() const;
    const sf::Transform& getInverseTransform() const;
private:
    sf::RectangleShape _btnShape;
};
```